# Concatenate many columns to one comma separate string and insert into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lots of concatenation posts here but can't seem to find the solution to this:

I have a table with 20 columns:

ID   Col 1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4  etc....

I need to concatenate all columns together so that I have two columns:

ID MasterCommaDelimColumn

Then I need to insert this into a new table. The problem seems to be the commas. I can concatenate everything together, but when I add the commas, it sees  them as separate columns, and the insert fails.

**EDIT:**

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)
CREATE TABLE #AgesServedGroup(
       provider_id INT, Infant VarChar(4), Preschool VarChar(4),
       SchoolAge VarChar(4), Adolescent VarChar(4), YoungAdult VarChar(4),
       Transition VarChar(4), Adult VarChar(4), Senior VarChar(4))

BEGIN
   SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #AgesServedGroup (provider_id, Infant, Preschool,
               SchoolAge,Adolescent,YoungAdult,Transition,Adult,Senior)
           SELECT provider_id,
             CASE WHEN provider_age_served_infant = 1 THEN 8 END AS Infant,
             CASE WHEN provider_age_served_pre_school = 1 THEN 13 END AS Preschool,
             CASE WHEN provider_age_served_school_age = 1 THEN 12 END AS SchoolAge,
             CASE WHEN provider_age_served_adolescent = 1 THEN 76 END AS Adolescent,
             CASE WHEN provider_age_served_young_adult = 1 THEN 77  END AS YoungAdult,
             CASE WHEN provider_age_served_transition = 1 THEN 78 END AS Transition,
             CASE WHEN provider_age_served_adult = 1 THEN 79  END AS Adult,
             CASE WHEN provider_age_served_senior = 1 THEN 80  END AS Senior
          FROM  dbo.provider_age_served'
     EXEC (@SQL);
END

 --Combine the ages served code
 CREATE TABLE #AgesServed(
         provider_id int,
         AgesServed VarChar(100))

BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #AgesServed (provider_id, AgesServed)
                SELECT provider_id, Infant + Preschool + SchoolAge +
                      Adolescent + YoungAdult + Transition + Adult + Senior
               FROM #AgesServedGroup'
    EXEC (@SQL);
END

INSERT INTO ProviderExport (link_name, cat_id, link_featured)
SELECT provider_id,CONVERT(varchar(100),AgesServed), 0
FROM #AgesServed 

DROP TABLE #AgesServedGroup
DROP TABLE #AgesServed
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

```
--Create the Ages Served Codes
  CREATE TABLE #AgesServedGroup(
  provider_id INT, Infant VarChar(4), Preschool VarChar(4), SchoolAge VarChar(4), Adolescent   VarChar(4), 
  YoungAdult VarChar(4), Transition VarChar(4), Adult VarChar(4), Senior VarChar(4))

  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #AgesServedGroup (provider_id, Infant, Preschool, SchoolAge,Adolescent,YoungAdult, Transition,Adult,Senior) 
  SELECT provider_id, CASE WHEN provider_age_served_infant = 1 THEN 8 END AS Infant, 
          CASE WHEN provider_age_served_pre_school = 1 THEN 13 END AS Preschool, 
          CASE WHEN provider_age_served_school_age = 1 THEN 12 END AS SchoolAge, 
          CASE WHEN provider_age_served_adolescent = 1 THEN 76 END AS Adolescent, 
          CASE WHEN provider_age_served_young_adult = 1 THEN 77 END AS YoungAdult, 
          CASE WHEN provider_age_served_transition = 1 THEN 78 END AS Transition, 
          CASE WHEN provider_age_served_adult = 1 THEN 79 END AS Adult, 
          CASE WHEN provider_age_served_senior = 1 THEN 80 END AS Senior
   FROM  dbo.provider_age_served        
  END

  --Combine the ages served code
  CREATE TABLE #AgesServed(
  provider_id int,  AgesServed VarChar(100))

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #AgesServed (provider_id, AgesServed) SELECT provider_id,
    CASE WHEN Infant Is Not Null THEN Infant + ',' ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN Preschool Is Not Null THEN Preschool + ',' ELSE '' END +  
    CASE WHEN SchoolAge Is Not Null THEN SchoolAge + ',' ELSE '' END +  
    CASE WHEN Adolescent Is Not Null THEN Adolescent + ',' ELSE '' END +  
    CASE WHEN YoungAdult Is Not Null THEN YoungAdult + ',' ELSE '' END +  
    CASE WHEN Transition Is Not Null THEN Transition + ',' ELSE '' END +  
    CASE WHEN Adult Is Not Null THEN Adult + ',' ELSE '' END + 
    CASE WHEN Senior Is Not Null THEN Senior ELSE '' END FROM #AgesServedGroup      
  END

  --Add the ages served master code
  BEGIN
    UPDATE #AgesServed SET AgesServed = '1,' + AgesServed WHERE AgesServed <> ''
  END

  --Trim the trailing comma
  BEGIN
    UPDATE #AgesServed SET AgesServed = LEFT(AgesServed, len(AgesServed) -1) WHERE RIGHT(AgesServed,1) = ','
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

For MS-SQL it's going to depend on the data types for the columns and if they are nullable, but something like this should work if everything is a *char type and not null.

```
select  1 as id
        ,'Hello' as col1
        ,' ' as col2
        ,'world' as col3
        ,'!' as col4
into newtable_tbl

select id
      , col1 + ',' + col2 + ',' + col3 + ',' + col4
from  newtable_tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, this sounds like a horrible idea.

But here's what it would look like.

```
create table #ccat (id int identity (1,1) primary key, MasterCommaDelimColumn varchar(max));

Insert into #ccat (MasterCommaDelimColumn)
Select cast(c1 as varchar)
        + ','+ cast(c2 as varchar)
        + ','+ cast(c3 as varchar)
from (values(1,2,3),(3,4,5),(6,7,8))g(c1,c2,c3);

select * from #ccat;

drop table #ccat;
```

Comment: I don't understand the 'from'. Whats the 'g'? Im in ms sql.

Comment: The 'from (...)' syntax is a selection from a subquery, the subquery needs to have a name.  I used "g" as the subquery name.  Sql2008 allows the use of a values list as the equivalent of a subquery.  So, i'm querying from a virtual table called g.

Comment: @jmoreno - I think you forgot to enclose the whole thing in quotes so it is treated as a single string by the INSERT

Comment: I was stupidly doing the whole thing as dynamic sql. Will post final code in a moment.

Comment: @Leigh: No, enclosing the whole thing in quotes would INSERT the expression, not the result of the expression.  I typed that up by hand, and I had left out the parenthesis around the MasterCommaDelimColumn, but otherwise it works and returns 3 rows, with a comma delimited string as the second column.

Comment: @Jmoreno - Sorry enclose was probably the wrong word. I meant at the beginning and end ie `''''+ col +''''` But you're totally right. I was looking at their earlier dynamic sql and it must have fried my brain ;)